# Experimental distinction between neutrinos and antineutrinos

Tags: particle-physics, cosmology, antimatter, neutrinos, chirality

How can we experimentally distinguish left-handed neutrinos from right-handed antineutrinos when we do not know a priori their creation process (for example in the case of cosmological neutrinos)?

Comment: Didn’t you answer your question in the question? Neutrinos are left-handed and anti-neutrinos are right-handed. Just measure their chirality by having them interact with lab-made particles of known chirality

Comment: this article on detecting high energy antineutrinos is relevant https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-00486-1 . Accumulating such events would allow to check with the standard  model the number of antineutrinos in what is the "neutrino flux" in the Icecube

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.15051 the announcement

Answer (score 1):

Lepton number is conserved in charged-current interactions (and, so far as we know, everywhere else). When a matter neutrino undergoes charged-current scattering, by emitting/absorbing a $W^\pm$, it creates a matter electron with negative charge. But when an antimatter neutrino undergoes charged-current scattering, it creates an antimatter electron with positive charge.

The chiral restriction of charged-current interactions, to left-handed particles and right-handed antiparticles, is an experimental result which requires you to distinguish matter from antimatter independently. The first historical result was published by Lederman and collaborators in 1957; it’s the article on the next page after the Wu et al. discovery of parity-violating oriented decays. Without re-reading, my recollection is that Lederman was able to measure the polarization of the muons and electrons produced in pion decays, and set limits on the neutrino polarization from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you partly have answered question yourself, but wiki [about neutrino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino) says it all :

> neutrino $\to~~~~~$ chirality: **L**eft, $~~$weak isospin: $\boldsymbol {+}\frac 12$, lepton number  $\boldsymbol{+}1$

> antineutrino $\to$  chirality: **R**ight, weak isospin: $\boldsymbol {-}\frac 12$, lepton number $\boldsymbol{−}1$

So you can distinguish them by all three properties combined.

Comment: It would be good to describe actual physics experiments rather than mere mathematical abstractions.